# I am learning Data Structures and came across Dijkstra's algorithm to get shortest path from one node (source) to another (destination)

Tags: java, data-structures, graph, dijkstra

I have encountered a problem in which I am asked to find the shortest path from a source node to a destination node and the shortest path from the destination node back to the source node.

The printPath methods output the shortest path taken from the source to the destination by using recursion to backtrack to the starting node then to the last node.

**printPath methods:**

```
/**
 * Driver routine to handle unreachables and print total cost.
 * It calls recursive routine to print shortest path to
 * destNode after a shortest path algorithm has run.
 */
public void printPath( String destName )
{
    Vertex w = vertexMap.get( destName );
    if( w == null )
        throw new NoSuchElementException( "Destination vertex not found" );
    else if( w.dist == INFINITY )
        System.out.println( destName + " is unreachable" );
    else
    {
        System.out.print( "(Cost is: " + w.dist + ") " );
        printPath( w );
        System.out.println( );
    }
}

/**
 * Recursive routine to print shortest path to dest
 * after running shortest path algorithm. The path
 * is known to exist.
 */
private void printPath( Vertex dest )
{
    String val;

    if( dest.prev != null )
    {
        printPath( dest.prev );
        // System.out.print( " to " );
        System.out.print(' ');
    }
    System.out.print( dest.name );
}
```

**Dijkstra's code**

```
/**
 * Single-source weighted shortest-path algorithm. (Dijkstra) 
 * using priority queues based on the binary heap
 */
public void dijkstra( String startName )
{
    PriorityQueue<Path> pq = new PriorityQueue<Path>( );

    Vertex start = vertexMap.get( startName );
    if( start == null )
        throw new NoSuchElementException( "Start vertex not found" );

    clearAll( );
    pq.add( new Path( start, 0 ) ); start.dist = 0;

    int nodesSeen = 0;
    while( !pq.isEmpty( ) && nodesSeen < vertexMap.size( ) )
    {
        Path vrec = pq.remove( );
        Vertex v = vrec.dest;
        if( v.scratch != 0 )  // already processed v
            continue;

        v.scratch = 1;
        nodesSeen++;

        for( Edge e : v.adj )
        {
            Vertex w = e.dest;
            double cvw = e.cost;

            if( cvw < 0 )
                throw new GraphException( "Graph has negative edges" );

            if( w.dist > v.dist + cvw )
            {
                w.dist = v.dist +cvw;
                w.prev = v;
                pq.add( new Path( w, w.dist ) );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Input**

```
D C 10
A B 12
D B 23
A D 87
E D 43
B E 11
C A 19
C B 8
```

In my main method, when I run:

```
dijkstra("B")
printPath("D")
```

I get this output:

```
(Cost is: 54.0) B E D
```

However, since I need to find the shortest path back to the source, the output required is:

```
(Cost is: 72.0) B E D C B
```

What is it that I should alter in the dijkstra's code or the printPath methods to get the required output?

Comment: Based on your example, I understand that you want the graph to be directed (i.e. they can only be traversed one way). In this scenario, you cannot find the shortest path from the destination back to the start based on the Dijkstra tree originating from the start. Either do a second Dijkstra run originating from the destination, or a second Dijkstra run originating from the source with the edges inverted (the first option would be easier).